# Wordpress page.php cant find images?

Tags: php, html, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm practicing WordPress and are now stuck.

When I look at front-page.php in my browser, all pictures are visible, but when I look at page.php in the browser, none of the images are visible,
They both have identical paths to some images, yet page.php wont display any pictures, it is like it cant find the images or something.

I have tried to hardcode the img path, but with no luck.

Below is my Page.php code

```
<?php get_header();?> <!--- There are an image inside the header aswell, it will not display when I look at page.php in browser--->
<div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <div class="row rounded p-5"> 
            <?php the_content();?>
        </div> 
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>
    <img src="wp-content/themes/Newtheme/bilder/cosmic-heart-of-the-universe-shawn-dall.jpg">
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: what is the generated path for page.php file? and what is for front page

Comment: in browser: 
http://localhost/wordpress/side1/ 
is for page.php and
http://localhost/wordpress/ 
is for front-page.php. 

both page.php and front-page.php are located inside 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Newtheme

Comment: try replace src of img tag with : <img src="/wp-content/themes/Newtheme/bilder/cosmic-heart-of-the-universe-shawn-dall.jpg">

Comment: Check this `src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bilder/cosmic-heart-of-the-universe-shawn-dall.jpg"`you need to do some searching before asking the question. wordpress has some functions that return the site URL, plugin directory, and theme directory.

Comment: And if not working share the image link that generated for front-page and page.php, not those that you do in coding, do you familiar with the inspect element? @OleKristian

Comment: Au nguyen, ill try your solution when i have access to my laptop.

Comment: Nasser, I tried that function, but with No luck, maybe I implemented it the wrong way, I have not learned php yet, its on my list.

Comment: Check your page source code for img src and just act accordingly.

Comment: Alright, <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>  Solved the problem.